# how grep text upto next space?

Tags: command-line, awk, sed, grep, pcregrep

```
7/04/27 10:50:17 INFO Master: Driver submitted org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper
17/04/27 10:50:17 INFO Master: Launching driver driver-20170427105017-0000 on worker worker-20170427103840-192.168.5.242-7078
17/04/27 10:50:22 INFO Master: 192.168.5.5:53156 got disassociated, removing it.
17/04/27 10:50:22 INFO Master: 192.168.5.5:37668 got disassociated, removing it.
17/04/27 10:50:22 INFO Master: 192.168.5.5:53154 got disassociated, removing it.
17/04/27 10:55:27 INFO Master: Registering app ETL DataPipeline App
17/04/27 10:55:27 INFO Master: Registered app ETL DataPipeline App with ID app-20170427105527-0000
17/04/27 10:55:27 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20170427105527-0000/0 on worker worker-20170427103842-192.168.5.175-7078
17/04/27 10:55:27 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20170427105527-0000/1 on worker worker-20170427103838-192.168.5.37-7078
17/04/27 11:08:25 INFO Master: Asked to kill driver driver-20170427105017-0000
17/04/27 11:08:25 INFO Master: Kill request for driver-20170427105017-0000 submitted
17/04/27 11:08:26 INFO Master: Received unregister request from application app-20170427105527-0000
```

How i will get driver-20170427105017-0000 and respective 192.168.5.242 and similarly how to grep app-20170427105527-0000/0 and its respective 192.168.5.175 .

Comment: Please confirm whether all the addresses that is needed to be filtered out is a private address (i.e will start with 192.168 ..)

Comment: the rules of matching are unclear. Can you elaborate why one `driver` should be matched while another - skipped?

Comment: yes these are private address .

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest actually i want all driver with its ip address. both driver is same.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` to get *all* `driver` and `executor` messages related to "Launching":

```
$ sed -n -E 's/^.*Launching (driver|executor) ([^ ]*).*worker-[0-9]*-([^-]*).*$/\2 \3/p' file.in
driver-20170427105017-0000 192.168.5.242
app-20170427105527-0000/0 192.168.5.175
app-20170427105527-0000/1 192.168.5.37
```

- `[^ ]*` will match any number of any characters, except space.
- `\2` and `\3` are back-references to what's matched by the second and third parentheses respectively. The second parentheses contains `[^ ]*` and will match the text after `Launching driver` or `Launching executor`, and the third parentheses  contains `[^-]*` and will match the IP address (up to the `-` which terminates the address).
- `^` and `$` in `s/^...$/.../p` anchors the regular expression at the start and end of the line, while `p` tells `sed` to "print" the result of the substitution if one is made.

Alternatively, and possibly more robust because of less regular expression magic, using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/Launching/ { split($NF, a, "-"); print $7, a[3] }' file.in
```

Comment: can you explain `([^ ]*)` and `*$/\2 \3/p` ? Thanks

Comment: @AshishK Updated my answer.